# Proper way to update static variable periodically

Tags: java

I have a static variable that I load at the beginning of a class. I want to update the variable every hour. The question is what is the proper way of doing this?

The way I am trying to do it is the following but it requires the method that updates the static variable to be in every constructor:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MyClass {

    private static String globalString = "";

    // initialize lastUpdate with two hours back to make sure first update happens
    private static Date lastUpdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (2 * (3600 * 1000)));


    MyClass() {
        updateGlobalString();

        // DO MORE STUFF HERE...
    }


    MyClass(String string) {
        updateGlobalString();

        // DO MORE STUFF HERE...
    }

    private synchronized void updateGlobalString() {
        // check if we need to update
        if (lastUpdate.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (3600 * 1000)))) {

            // DO THINGS TO UPDATE globalString HERE...

            lastUpdate = new Date();
        }
    }
}
```

Any other ideas/better way of doing it?

Comment: You can use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule a task to run every hour.

Comment: It would be better if you have a cache library that handles the live span of an entry by one hour instead of programming it.

Comment: You can use constructor chaining, put `updateGlobalString()` in first constructor and use `this();` call in others.

Answer (score 5):

You should use some sort of timer to do the update.

For example, use a ScheduledExecutorService to have a task run every hour, which updates the field.  Something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static volatile String globalString;
    private static ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    static {
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               // DO THINGS TO UPDATE globalString HERE...
            }
        },
        0, 1, TimeUnit.HOUR);
    }

    // Rest of class, without having to worry about the updateGlobalString
    // method, or the lastUpdate variable, or anything like that
    ...
}
```

Note that because the variable is being accessed by multiple threads, you'll need to ensure that your code is threadsafe.  (This is definitely the case with the timer example above, but is likely to be the case with your current approach too.)

The easiest way to simply ensure that updates are seen is to mark the `globalString` variable as `volatile`, but depending on how the class is used other approaches may be more appropriate.

Comment: This is a great approach. Definitely much much better from what I was thinking. One Q if you don't mind: Why the ScheduledExecutorService is defined in the class level and not just within the static block since the static block executes just one time at the beginning? I guess there is a good reason for it. Just curious

Comment: One more Q is what if the class is being accessed by multiple Threads? This approach will give IllegalMonitorStateException. Right?

Comment: @user2287359 I declared the executor service at the class level because I think it's slightly clearer that way (there *is* a static executor service either way).  Plus it means that you have a reference to it if you ever want to stop future updates for whatever reason.  As for your `IllegalMonitorStateException` question, this exception is only ever thrown if you try to call `obj.wait()` or `obj.notify()` without holding `obj`'s monitor (i.e. synchronizing on it).  My code doesn't need these methods - it uses an executor instead - and so should not throw that exception under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the Executors framework:

```
public class MyClass {
   public static String globalString = "";

   private static ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

   //static block of code
   static {
     s.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           globalString = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
        }
     }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOUR);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Using a period of `60 * 60 SECONDS` seems to be missing the point of `TimeUnit`... :)

Comment: +1 anyway - there's nothing wrong with what you had before, and it does work, it just makes me smile.